# database as a microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices

i had a project with non-microservices design. but now would like to implement it to be microservices. to split the project to multiple microservice module is not hard, but i did some research on database design pattern for microservices, each microservices should have own schema or own database.

[image]

my question is may i make the database source to be a microservice? and other microservice want to read and write data need to connect to database microservice? because currently only one database and all tables in one schema. i don't want to split the tables to different schema.

[image]

Comment: This resource may be useful – https://microservices.io/refactoring/

Comment: Having a service to front the database would defeat the purpose. Having multiple databases reduces contention. This way keeps the contention.

Comment: im using spring jpa, so may i still use the one database and one schema, but split entity and repository class file to each microservices?  is that work? thx